# Wie hört sich 'zuzumachen' an - als ein Wort oder drei?

Tags: pronunciation, compound

> Er hatte vergessen, das Fenster **zuzumachen.**

So soll das letzte Wort ja aussehen. Aber hört/empfindet/versteht man es nicht eher als 'ZU zu machen', was eine solche Schreibweise gewissermaßen rechtfertigen dürfte?

Comment: Die Korrektheit von "zu zu machen" rührt nicht von der Aussprache des Wortes. Ich lese es jedenfalls immer mit klaren Pausen.

Comment: In dem Fall ist es an zu em pfehlen, an sei ner Aus Sprache zu ar beiten.

Comment: @EagleFliesBanana: Liest du dann auch *»Zuzug«* mit klaren Pausen? (Ich verwende jetzt absichtlich mal nur Kleinschreibung, um den Einfluss von Großbuchstaben, die man beim Hören ohnehin nicht wahrnimmt, auszuschalten: *»der **zuzug** hält unvermindert an« = »der **zu zug** hält unvermindert an«*)  Und was ist mit *»kurzzuschließen«?* Auch mit klaren Pausen? (*»Vermeide, die die Drähte **kurzzuschließen.**« = »Vermeide, die die Drähte **kurz zu schließen.**«*)

Comment: Bravo Bakunin! ein Ideechen übertrieben vielleicht, aber 'an empfehlen' - warum nicht? Schade, dass die Schreibreformer das Zusammenschreiben bei "trennbaren" Verben nicht als unnoetig erkannt und abgeschafft haben - man hätte dann ganze Kapiteln aus der Grammatik streichen koennen.

Comment: @Bernhard: Ja, das stimmt - und wenn man die ganze Grammatik abgeschafft hätte, dann hätte man alle Kapitel aus der Grammatik streichen können und "Kapiteln" wäre auch ein korrekter Plural von "Kapitel". Vielleicht ist aber auch ein Unterschied zwischen einem "viel versprechenden" und einem "vielversprechenden" Politiker und es macht einen Unterschied ob man was "zusammenschreibt" oder "zusammen schreibt".

Comment: Ja, Bakunin, touché! Aber das heißt bei uns "nitpicking". Ich halte daran fest, auch wenn ich meinen Kuli ganz fest halten muss, dass das Zusammenschreiben bei den meisten angeblich trennbaren Verben eine an sich unnoetige Schreibkonvention darstellt.

Comment: Ich empfehle die Lesarten "Zuzu machen" und "zu zumachen" in die Erwägungen kreativ mit ein zu bringen.

Answer (score 2):

Die Partikel trägt immer die Hauptbetonung des Prädikats. "ZUzumachen" nicht anders als "AUFzumachen" oder "ABzumachen".

Comment: ....  und die alternative Schreibweise?

Comment: Die Rechtschreibung ist festgelegt...

Answer (score 2):

Die Frage geht von der Annahme aus, Getrennt- und Zusammenschreibung wäre hörbar. Das trifft nicht zu. Es handelt sich um eine reine orthografische Konvention.

Bei langjähriger Vertrautheit mit der Getrenntschreibung liegt zwar die Annahme nahe, es existierte auch eine Getrenntaussprache. Dies ist aber nicht der Fall.

- Die Untersuchung vor Sprachaufnahmen zeigt sofort, das die Aussprache nicht zwischen den Wörtern trennt.
- Die [*scriptio continua*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scriptio_continua), also das Schreiben ohne Wortabstände, ist in verschiedenen Sprachkulturen verbreitet.
- Bei Kindern, die das Schreiben lernen, ist es ebenfalls nicht ungewöhnlich, dass sie alles zusammenschreiben, weil Wortabstände eben nicht zu hören sind.
- In den nördlichen regionalen Varianten des Deutschen ist vor Vokalanlaut ein [Glottisschlag](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glottaler_Plosiv) üblich. Dabei entsteht der Eindruck einer abgehackten Aussprache. Dies wird jedoch nicht etwa durch eine Trennung in der Aussprache verursacht, sondern durch einen zusätzlichen Konsonanten, der nicht geschrieben wird. Um diesen Konsonanten herum gibt er aber ebenso wenig eine Trennung in der Aussprache wie bei anderen Konsonanten – die Aussprache von *die Acht* mit Glottisschlag ist also genauso wenig getrennt wie die Aussprache von *die Pacht.* Ausserdem korreliert der Glottisschlag gar nicht mit dem Wortzwischenraum, denn es gibt Wortzwischenräume ohne Glottisschlag (z.B. *die Pacht, die Macht)* und Glottisschläge ohne Wortzwischenraum (z.B. *geachtet, Verachtung).*

Answer (score 1):

Nein. Wird als ein Wort gesprochen, mit einem rasanten *zuzu*.

Comment: Gesprochen schon, aber als einziges Wort verstanden/empfunden?

Answer (score 1):

Das Wort *»zuzumachen«* wird ohne Pausen zwischen den einzelnen Silben ausgesprochen.

Wiktionary hat nicht nur für jedes deutsches Wort einen Eintrag in seiner Stammform, sondern es gibt dort auch für jede deklinierte Form einen Eintrag, und jeder dieser Einträge zeigt die Aussprache dieser Wortform in IPA-Lautschrift an. Beim Wort **[zuzumachen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/zuzumachen)** findet man diese Lautschrift:

[ˈt͡suːt͡suˌmaxn̩]

Das Wort besteht aus vier gesprochenen Silben:

- **zu** [ˈt͡suː]
  Die erste Silbe ist jene, die von allen vier Silben am stärksten betont wird, also die Hauptbetonung hat. Das wird in der Lautschrift durch das Zeichen »**ˈ**« am Beginn der Silbe gekennzeichnet. Diese Silbe hat einen langen Vokal, was mit dem Dehnungszeichen »**ː**« direkt hinter dem Vokal angezeigt wird.
- **zu** [t͡su]
  Die zweite Silbe verwendet zwar die gleich drei Laute wie die erste Silbe, aber die zweite Silbe ist unbetont (kein Betonungszeichen in der Lautschrift) und ihr Vokal ist kurz (kein Dehnungszeichen).
- **ma** [ˌma]
  Das Zeichen »**ˌ**« ist ebenfalls ein Betonungszeichen, es kennzeichnet aber nicht die Hauptbetonung, sondern eine Nebenbetonung. Das nichtvorhandene Dehnungszeichen signalisiert eine kurze Aussprache des Vokals.
- **chen** [xn̩]
  Das Lautschriftzeichen »**x**« steht für den CH-Laut, der in deutschen Wörtern unter anderem nach dem Vokal [a] gesprochen wird. Das Auffallende an dieser Silbe ist, dass in ihr kein Vokal gesprochen wird. Das Zeichen »**e**« existiert nur als Buchstabe in der geschriebenen Form, in der gesprochenen Form gibt es für diesen Buchstaben aber keine Entsprechung. Stattdessen wird der Buchstabe »**n**« vokalisiert, also klingend ausgesprochen. Um das anzuzeigen, wir in der Lautschrift unter dem jeweiligen Konsonanten das diakritische Zeichen » ̩« gesetzt. Eine Vokalisierung ist nur bei den sogenannten sonoren Konsonanten möglich, das sind m, n, r und l, und sie findet nur in Endsilben von deutschen Erbwörtern statt. Solche Silben nennt man auch *Reduktionssilben.*
  Mit dem Ersetzen eines echten Vokals durch einen vokalisierten Konsonanten geht auch eine deutliche Schwächung der Betonung einher, weswegen die vierte und letzte Silbe von *»zuzumachen«* jene ist, die am schwächsten betont ist. Für diese Schwächung der Betonung gibt es in der Lautschrift kein eigenes Symbol, aber diese Schwächung ist ohnehin eine Folge des Fehlens eines echten Vokals.

Mehr über das IPA ([internationales phonetisches Alphabet](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationales_Phonetisches_Alphabet)) findet man bei Wikipedia, und es gibt dort auch eine separate Seite mit einer sehr übersichtlichen [Liste der IPA-Zeichen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_IPA-Zeichen).

---

Es gibt übrigens auch Wörter, in denen dreimal hintereinander die Silbe *zu* vorkommt:

> Ich habe vergessen, den Rucksack zuzuzurren.

---

Damit ist die Frage eigentlich beantwortet, ich möchte aber noch etwas Prinzipielleres hinzufügen, das gut zu dieser Thematik passt:

Bei solchen Fragen muss man sich immer vergegenwärtigen, dass das geschriebene Wort nur eine Methode ist, um Sprache zu transportieren und zu konservieren. Sprache ist ursprünglich etwas das gesprochen wird: Der Sender der Nachricht transformiert Ideen in Schallschwingungen und der Empfänger transformiert diese Schwingungen zurück in neue Ideen, die im Idealfall mit den Ideen des Senders übereinstimmen. Die Schrift hingegen ist eine vergleichsweise neue Erfindung, jedenfalls im Vergleich zur Dauer, in der Menschen sich durch Sprechen und Hören verständigt haben.

Vor diesem Hintergrund sollte die Frage daher nicht lauten, wie man bestimmte Zeichenfolgen ausspricht, sondern die eigentliche Frage ist, wie man die Schallschwingungen, die die eigentliche Sprache sind, möglichst gut in Form von Zeichenfolgen abbildet. Und das führt zur Frage, was denn überhaupt ein gesprochenes Wort ist, denn man hätte ja eigentlich gerne, dass die Leerstellen, die man beim Schreiben zwischen den geschriebenen Wörtern macht, mit den Wortgrenzen der gesprochenen Sprache übereinstimmen.

Aber allein schon die Existenz von Fragen wie *»Schreibt man "vertrauenerweckend" zusammen oder getrennt?«* oder die Tatsache, dass z.B. Schopenhauer die beiden Wörter *»da«* und *»ist«* immer zusammengeschrieben hat (*»daist«*) zeigt aber, dass das in der gesprochenen Sprache weit weniger eindeutig ist, als man gerne glauben möchte. Tatsächlich gibt es gar keine sprachwissenschaftliche Definition für den Begriff *»Wort«,* und verschiedene Sprachen gehen damit auch unterschiedlich um. Und der Grund dafür ist, dass wir beim Sprechen bei den meisten Wortgrenzen gar keine Pausen machen.

Schauspieler und andere professionelle Sprecher, die versuchen möglichst verständlich zu sprechen, machen deutlich mehr und längere Pausen zwischen den Wörtern als Alltagssprecher. Während *»mit dem«* bei Profisprechern noch nach zwei getrennten Wörtern klingt, macht der Alltagssprecher daraus *»mitem«* und in der Umgangssprachen sogar *»mitm«.*

Dafür machen wir beim Sprechen aber manchmal mitten im Wort eine Pause, die im geschriebenen Text nicht als Leerzeichen wiedergegeben wird. Das *»Betttuch«* spricht man immer als *»Bett Tuch«* aus, und das *»Krepppapier«* immer als *»Krepp Papier«,* obwohl es keinen Zweifel daran gibt, dass diese Wörter zusammenzuschreiben sind.

**Was heißt das nun?**

Das heißt, dass Leerzeichen in einem Text nicht immer als kurze Pausen auszusprechen sind, und es heißt aber auch, das man manchmal beim Sprechen Pausen macht, obwohl es im Text gar kein Leerzeichen gibt. Ober noch prägnanter: Geschrieben Wörter und gesprochene Wörter mit den jeweiligen Wortgrenzen sind zwei Konzepte, die manchmal nicht viel miteinander zu tun haben.

Comment: ich hätte es besser gefunden, hättest geschrieben du, "Der Sender der Nachricht transformiert Ideen in Schall[geschwindigkeit]". Ich bin aber auch wieder komisch.

Answer (score -3):

Im Prinzip hört es sich an wie *zu-gemacht* mit Betonung auf der ersten Silbe, wie @Alazon bestätigt, nur sagt niemand

> * Das Fenster ist zugemacht

sondern schlicht

> das Fenster ist zu

sowie die entsprechende Aufforderung auch lautet "Fenster zu!" bzw. "Bitte schließen Sie die Fenster". Dem Rechtschreibrat dürfte dieser Sonderfall also im Prinzip herzlich egal sein, weil es aus stilistischen Gründen un-zu-lässig ist, aber dennoch statthaft. Denn offensichtlich liegt ein da ein Konflikt begraben

> Er hat vergessen, das Fenster zu schließen

> ? Er hat vergessen, das Fenster zu zu schließen (bzw. *zuzuschließen*)

bei letzterem dürfte es sich um eine Mischform handeln (daneben *abschließen*, zu-Partizip *abzuschließen*), wenn man annehmen darf, dass *zu* nicht prepositionales Adverb ist, sondern über *ziehen, zurren* und dergleichen vermutlich erst über Umwege ins Hochdeutsche gelangt ist, da statt *Zug* regional *Zuch* gilt und im Adverb, etwa "* die *zuhe*" oder "* die zuhene Truhe", intervokalische Assimilation zu erwarten ist.

Dazugehörig sind engl. *tug* und sag ich ma so nordseegermanisch *tow* bzw. *Tau*, vb. *vertäuen*, die Grimm (Deutsches Wörterbuch) scheinbar nicht kennt, BMZ und Lexer ebensowenig, aber Adelung schon (s. woerterbuchnetz), Pfeifer auch (s. DWDS), der Adelungs Vergleich mit *ziehen* jedoch nicht mitgeht.

> Sie gehören zu einem Verb mnd. mnl. nl. *touwen* ‘ausrüsten, bereiten, zustande bringen, fertigmachen’, intransitiv ‘eilen’, unpersönlich ‘vonstatten gehen’, aengl. *tāwian* ‘fertigmachen’, anord. tawiðō ‘ich machte, verfertigte’ (Gallehus, vor 400), got. *taujan* ‘machen, tun, wirken’ und ahd. *zawen* ‘glücken, gelingen’ (9. Jh.), ‘färben’ (10. Jh.), *zouwen* ‘zurechtmachen, (ein Eisenstück) bearbeiten’ (11. Jh.), mhd. *zouwen, zöuwen* ‘tun, verfahren, machen, fertigmachen, bereiten’, reflexiv ‘sich bereitmachen, schmücken, rüsten, beeilen’.

Wegen nebenbdeutungen ist auch ein Zusammenhang mit engl. inf. *to* nicht auszuschließen, die eventuell in altgriechischen Konversationspartikeln *Τ᾽ ἌΡ*, *ἌΡ* etc. zu erkennen sind, die jedenfalls auf **h2er- zurückgeführt werden können; weiteres höchst unklar. Bei mir heißt es folgerichtig:

> Mach die Tür ran.

siehe dazu auch *verriegelt und verrammelt*.

Andererseits deutet *schließen* auf lateinisch *cludo* hin, aber s-moblie bleibt unerklärlich. Sowie Staats-Klausur zu einem Entschluss kommen muss, steht demgegenüber eigentlich der *Zuschluss* (?), *Anschluss* oder *zu jemandem aufschließen*.

Hier ist vermutlich besser *di(s)-* anzuschließen, vgl. *disclose*, urindogermanisch **dwis-* "entzwei", **dwo- "zwei", **wi-* "wider, wieder". Schließlich sind die typischen Colocationen mit *lehnen* eben *gegen* bzw. *an*; nur scheidet engl. *on* in diesem Ansatz aus. So bleibt also nur *gegen*, *angegen* (engl. *against*), bzw. *wider*, daher etwa "die Tür wieder ran machen" (*? wiederan*), völlig unklar.

Der übliche Vergleich *zu*, lat. *de* macht meines Erachtens keinen Sinn an dieser Stelle.

---

PS: Um auf die eigentliche Frage zu rekurrieren

> Aber hört/empfindet/versteht man es nicht eher als 'ZU zu machen', was eine solche Schreibweise gewissermaßen rechtfertigen dürfte

Nein, derartige Großschreibung aller Lettern eines Wortes wird der Netiquette als "schreien" betrachtet.

Aber ja. Allenfalls geht es um Akzentsitz und Vokallänge, wobei das erste nie markiert wird weil es regelhaft aus dem Wortgefüge hervorgehen soll, immer auf der ersten Silbe außer bei Vorsilben. Da ist aber keine Vorsilbe.

Es verhält sich wie bei *Spaß machen*, bzw. häufig *Späße machen*, was wohl richtiger ist, sodass es **zue machen* lauten sollte (was eventuell in der Literatur nachweisbar sein muss).

Vermutlich sagen aber doch einige *z'machen*. Das wäre eine andere Frage. Vielleicht ist da der alte Dual von *Türe*, der kaum rekonstruierbar ist, eine Liaison eingegangen? Kurz zur Erklärung: Bairisch kennt den Dual noch im Gruß "pfärts enk" (angeblich *Führe euch Gott*). Dementsprechend müsste *mach-ts-Türe* zu erwarten sein. S. a. *Halt's Maul* bzw. selten genug "Hals-Maul". Da könnte sich althochdeutscher Artikel (s-Initial) mit neuerem *der, die, das* gekreuzt haben.

Ich will jetzt nicht behaupten, dem Zentralrat sei das nicht bewusst, oder dass das überhaupt relevant sei. Im Gegenteil war mir die veranschlagte Schreibweise *zuzumachen* bis eben nicht geläufig. Das wäre nachzutragen.

---

PS: Wahrscheinlich ist der Ansatz laut zu werden doch nicht falsch

> Wenn du reinkommst tritt dir die Schuhe ab und mach bitte die gottverdammte Tür ZU

> ODER BIST DU AUFMBAHNHOFGEBOREN?!?!?

> Krieg ich Plack bei sowat ehrlich ey hör ma.

Comment: Das doppelte "ist" im ersten Zitat ist keine Absicht, oder? Und: Entweder eine Sache muss sein, oder sie ist eventuell, aber eventuell muss ... nachweisbar sein" ist m.E. eine contradictio in adjecto.

Comment: " The principle of regularity is criticized at regular intervals. Some linguists argue that there are always exceptions which are not governed by a rule, and this is indeed often the case: comparative linguistics happens to be a historical science, and it is not always possible to discover explanations for everything that has happened in history" (Beekes, de Vaan (2011), pg. 56)